# Set number and message for RAISERROR in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, raiseerror

I wrote a stored procedure that saves card. I want to when `Barcode_Num` is duplicate, don't allow for adding and display message (I know that must use from `RAISERROR`), but I want set the number for `RAISERROR` and set message that is:

> *the card number 10000001(ex) is duplicate , and you don't allow add this*

I set this but didn't worked.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[SaveCards]
    @Barcode_Num int
    ,@Card_Status_ID int 
    ,@Card_Type_ID int
    ,@SaveDate varchar(10)
    ,@Save_User_ID int 

AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRAN Entrance
    Begin Try 
    if (select COUNT(*) from TBL_Cards where Barcode_Num = @Barcode_Num ) = 0
    begin
    INSERT INTO [Parking].[dbo].[TBL_Cards]
               ([Barcode_Num]
               ,[Card_Status_ID]
               ,[Card_Type_ID]
               ,[Save_Date]        
               ,[Save_User_ID])

         VALUES
               (@Barcode_Num
               ,@Card_Status_ID
               ,@Card_Type_ID
               ,@SaveDate
               ,@Save_User_ID
               )
          end
             else
                 begin 
                 --
                 declare @EndCardID int ;
             set @EndCardID= (  select Barcode_Num  from TBL_Cards  WHERE TBL_Cards.Card_ID = (SELECT MAX(Card_ID)
                             FROM TBL_Cards  ))

                 declare @CardID int ;
                 set @CardID= ( select Barcode_Num  from TBL_Cards  where Barcode_Num = @Barcode_Num)

                    --RAISERROR('قبلا کارتی ب اين شماره ثبت شده است.',50000,1)
                RAISERROR((N'the card number %d is duplicate',@CardID),50000,1);
             end   
        COMMIT TRAN Entrance
        END TRY

        Begin CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRAN Entrance
            DECLARE @Error_Number   int
            SET @Error_Number = ERROR_NUMBER()
            DECLARE @Error_Message  varchar(max)
            SET @Error_Message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
            DECLARE @Log_Error_ID   int
            EXEC [LogError] @Error_Number, @Error_Message OUTPUT, @Log_Error_ID, @Save_User_ID

            IF @Error_Message IS NOT NULL
                RAISERROR(@Error_Message,16,1)
            ELSE
                RAISERROR((N'the card number %d is duplicate',@CardID),16,1)

            END CATCH   
    END 

    Begin CATCH
            ROLLBACK TRAN Entrance
            DECLARE @Error_Number   int
            SET @Error_Number = ERROR_NUMBER()
            DECLARE @Error_Message  varchar(max)
            SET @Error_Message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
            DECLARE @Log_Error_ID   int
            EXEC [LogError] @Error_Number, @Error_Message OUTPUT, @Log_Error_ID, @Save_User_ID

            IF @Error_Message IS NOT NULL
                RAISERROR(@Error_Message,16,1)
            ELSE
                RAISERROR('قبلا کارتی با اين شماره ثبت شده است',16,1)

            END CATCH   

    END
```

Comment: Why don't you have a unique constraint on `Barcode_Num`? This will be more efficient than your code (and also avoid the race condition you currently have)

Comment: because i get this from user in C# winform

Comment: That is not any reason. Just create a unique constraint on that column then SQL Server will manage this for you. You can then catch the duplicate key error rather than raising your own error that needs to be caught.

Comment: My question is something else

Comment: my question is from RAISERROR

Comment: More recent versions of SQL server do include the value of the duplicate key in the duplicate key error message. Hopefully you do have a unique constraint on the table as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)s formatting facilities, the arguments come *after* the severity and state parameters:

```
RAISERROR('the card number %d is duplicate',16,1,@CardID)
```